# Change a number to a word using PHP

Tags: php

I have an equation in PHP that gives back a number. How do I turn the number into a word before returning it to HTML?

```
$progress = round($number);
1='Very Good';
2='Good';
3='Average';
4='Bad';
5='Very Bad';
return $progress;
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  Every variable should start with a $ sign.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt mean the numbers to come out like code I was just trying to show what I want the numbers to become

Comment: Oh, I see what you are getting at now.  I can provide you with an answer but several people have already beat me to it.

Comment: I know! Bazzinga that was fast

Comment: Thank you all! I wish I had your skills

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an associative array

```
$progress = round($number);

$progress_text = array(
1 => 'Very Good',
2 => 'Good',
3 => 'Average',
4 => 'Bad',
5 => 'Very Bad'
);

echo isset($progress_text[$progress]) ? $progress_text[$progress] : 'Unknown';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do it.

One is to create a function:

```
function wordify($number) {
    switch($number) {
        case 1:
            return 'Very Good';
            break;
        case 2:
            return 'Good';
            break;
        case 3:
            return 'Average';
            break;
        case 4:
            return 'Bad';
            break;
        case 5:
            return 'Very Bad';
            break;
        default:
            return 'error';
            break;
    }
}
```

Then to call it:

```
echo wordify(4); // outputs "Bad"
```

Comment: Won't the `return` already `break`?

Comment: @kingkero It would, but I wanted to teach OP to use breaks no matter what. It's a good practice, right? :)

Comment: I would either do returns after each case or, breaks after each case and a return at the end, but not both.

Comment: @bumperbox I would too, but this is not just about giving a working solution, but teaching PHP to someone who seems pretty new at it. I mean, I could've written something like `<?= array_values(array('vgood', 'good', 'avg', 'bad', 'vbad'))[$i-1]; ?>`, and it would work, but would it be any helpful? Would the OP learn anything from that?

Answer (score 1):

Place your numeric descriptions in an array and then return the array index corresponding to the number:

```
$progress = round($number);
$numbers = array(
    1 => 'Very Good',
    2 => 'Good',
    3 => 'Average',
    4 => 'Bad',
    5 => 'Very Bad',
);
if ( isset( $numbers[$progress] ) )
    return $numbers[$progress];
else
    return 'Unknown';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php

    $choice  = 1;//example number = 1
    $choices = array(
        1 => 'Very Good',
        2 => 'Good',
        3 => 'Average',
        4 => 'Bad',
        5 => 'Very Bad'
    );

    if (isset($choices[round($choice)])) echo $choices[round($choice)];
    else echo "NONE";


?>
```